# Manipulating a list of numbers - Python

Tags: python

Why am I receiving the following error when running this Python script on my list of numbers?

(where x = [1, 2, 3, 4])

**Script:**

```
x = []
for i,line in enumerate(sys.stdin):
    if i == 1:
         x = line.split()

x = list(map(int, x))
val = x[len(x)-1]
x.extend(val)

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "solution.py", line 13, in <module>
    x.extend(val)
TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable
```

Answer (score 3):

It should be `x.append(val)`. extend takes an iterable like a list or a generator.